# Запятая в предложениях с «в случае»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующей модели предложения: "В случае отсутствия детали(,) система не запустится"?

Или инверсия: "Они не откроют дверь(,) в случае отсутствия связи".

Или вот такой вариант: "В случае появления в комнате Владислава Алексеевича незамедлительно расспросите его о прошедшей встрече с Настасьей Ильиничной".

Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех трёх примерах запятую ставить не нужно. Обороты с предлогом «в случае» находятся в начале или в конце предложений, не разделяют подлежащее и сказуемое, не вызывают двусмысленности или неверного понимания своих границ.

> [**В СЛУЧАЕ (чего)**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_121)
>
> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «в случае», могут обособляться. О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в [Прил. 1](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1).
>
> ***В случае** ослушания музыкантов садили на гауптвахту, как простых солдат.* Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Верный раб. *Иван Павлыч Вологжанин неутомимо начал разъезжать по всем знакомым и собирать полезные сведения о житье-бытье крутогорских обывателей, дабы, **в случае** надобности, преподнесть этот букет господину ревизору и чрез то заявить свою деятельность и преданность.* М. Салтыков-Щедрин, Приезд ревизора. *И тогда, догадавшись, что я-то ведь тоже человек, я пустился в поиски самого себя, справедливо полагая, что **в случае** неудачи потеря для всех небольшая, а **в случае** удачи это находка для многих.* М. Анчаров, Сода-солнце.